# Why can't I delete all labels and properties in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I used "Match (n) detach delete n" to try delete everything in the graph, but in Neo4j Browser it still shows there is one label and a few properties. That looks like strange.

Please see my attached screenshot. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have indexes present, the labels and properties used in the indexes will show in the browser. Try looking at `:schema`.

Also keep note that this is meta data, it isn't necessarily the most accurate reflection of what's actually in your database.